# How to wrap all siblings in one class after a class? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have blog posts that has a featured image with content details like title, description and date.

```
<div id="blog-posts-loop">

    <div class="blog-home-wrap">
        <div class="blog-home-thumb">
            <a href="#" class="su-post-thumbnail">
            <img width="500" height="300" alt="welcome" class="post-thumbnail" src="src_of_img"></a>
        </div>

        <h2 class="blog-home-post-title">This is a title</h2>
        <div class="blog-home-post-excerpt"></div>
        <div class="blog-home-post-date">November 23, 2015</div>

    </div>

    <div class="blog-home-wrap">
        <div class="blog-home-thumb">
            <a href="#" class="su-post-thumbnail">
            <img width="500" height="300" alt="welcome" class="post-thumbnail" src="src_of_img"></a>
        </div>

        <h2 class="blog-home-post-title">This is a title</h2>
        <div class="blog-home-post-excerpt"></div>
        <div class="blog-home-post-date">November 23, 2015</div>

    </div>

    <div class="blog-home-wrap">
        <div class="blog-home-thumb">
            <a href="#" class="su-post-thumbnail">
            <img width="500" height="300" alt="welcome" class="post-thumbnail" src="src_of_img"></a>
        </div>

        <h2 class="blog-home-post-title">This is a title</h2>
        <div class="blog-home-post-excerpt"></div>
        <div class="blog-home-post-date">November 23, 2015</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**Desired output:** I want to wrap all the remaining details as a single div with class after every class="blog-home-thumb"

```
<div id="blog-posts-loop">

    <div class="blog-home-wrap">
        <div class="blog-home-thumb">
            <a href="#" class="su-post-thumbnail">
            <img width="500" height="300" alt="welcome" class="post-thumbnail" src="src_of_img"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="blog-home-content">
            <h2 class="blog-home-post-title">This is a title</h2>
            <div class="blog-home-post-excerpt"></div>
            <div class="blog-home-post-date">November 23, 2015</div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="blog-home-wrap">
        <div class="blog-home-thumb">
            <a href="#" class="su-post-thumbnail">
            <img width="500" height="300" alt="welcome" class="post-thumbnail" src="src_of_img"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="blog-home-content">
            <h2 class="blog-home-post-title">This is a title</h2>
            <div class="blog-home-post-excerpt"></div>
            <div class="blog-home-post-date">November 23, 2015</div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="blog-home-wrap">
        <div class="blog-home-thumb">
            <a href="#" class="su-post-thumbnail">
            <img width="500" height="300" alt="welcome" class="post-thumbnail" src="src_of_img"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="blog-home-content">
            <h2 class="blog-home-post-title">This is a title</h2>
            <div class="blog-home-post-excerpt"></div>
            <div class="blog-home-post-date">November 23, 2015</div>
        </div>

    </div>



</div>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please show us your attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over each `.blog-home-thumb` element, select all the following sibling elements using the [`.nextAll()` method,](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and then use the [`.wrapAll()` method](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vwwe05tx/)

```
$('.blog-home-thumb').each(function () {
    $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="blog-home-content"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Hi Josh. Thanks for the answer. You are great :)